# Is there any way to fix errors caused by Bootstrap when upgrading to React 18

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am following a guide to upgrade to React 18.  After completing the upgrade I am seeing errors on certain pages in my app.

```
ReactDOM.unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer() is no longer supported in React 18.
```

I am not using the `unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer()` function anywhere in my app, but when I look closer at what is causing these errors it seems to be caused my Bootstrap components.

Is there anyway to update this to remove the errors?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem with `react-bootstrap@v0.33.1` specifically when using `OverlayTrigger` component after upgrading to React 18. The warning message suggests to migrate to using portals. So I implemented a `CustomOverlayTrigger` component that leverages portals and referred to React's [portal documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) to do so. Note that this solution is for Bootstrap 3 usage of `OverlayTrigger` (react-bootstrap v0.33.1). It seems later versions of react-bootstrap got rid of using `ReactDOM.unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer`. If you are not in a position to migrate to later versions (like I am), this solution will help for this use case. I have not check thoroughly if other components use the deprecated method, but the approach might be the same.

First of all, I copied the original source of the `OverlayTrigger` component code located [here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/bs3-dev/src/OverlayTrigger.js). You will need to clean up the imports and include into your code the utils function `createChainedFunction` located [here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/bs3-dev/src/utils/createChainedFunction.js).

I then created a portal wrapper based off React's documentation that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const tooltipRoot = document.getElementById('tooltip-root');

class PortalWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    tooltipRoot.appendChild(this.el);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    tooltipRoot.removeChild(this.el);
  }

  render() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/destructuring-assignment
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.el);
  }
}

PortalWrapper.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),
    PropTypes.node,
  ]).isRequired,
};

export default PortalWrapper;
```

At the top, you can see the line `const tooltipRoot = document.getElementById('tooltip-root');`, I simply added in my `index.html` a div next to the react app's root div that will server as the anchor for my portal.

Then, back in the `CustomOverlayTrigger` component copied from react-bootstrap, I edited it in the follwing manner:

1. Remove all references to `this._overlay` and `this._mountNode` because the `PortalWrapper` now manages the mounting/unmounting. So I deleted `componentDidMount()`, `componentDidUpdate()`, `componentWillUnmount()` and `renderOverlay()`
2. I modified makeOverlay so that its result is wrapped by `PortalWrapper` so it became the following:

```
makeOverlay(overlay, props) {
    return (
      <PortalWrapper>
        <Overlay
          {...props}
          show={this.state.show}
          onHide={this.handleHide}
          target={this}
        >
          {overlay}
        </Overlay>
      </PortalWrapper>
    );
  }
```

3. Finally, I changed the render method's return statement to become:

```
return (<>
      {cloneElement(child, triggerProps)}
      {this.makeOverlay(overlay, props)}
    </>);
```

After this, I simply had to replace all my invocations to `OverlayTrigger` with `CustomOverlayTrigger` and I had the same result without the warning message.

Comment: Thank you!, I am facing this issue right now and I was thinking in forking the project to achieve the same thing you explained here. I am going to try this to see if my issues are gone.